# ¿Cómo sumarle días a una fecha ya generada en Angular11?

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo un código que me genera día, mes y año para formar una fecha D/M/A, lo que intento hacer es que después a esa fecha se le sume un x numero de días y formar una nueva fecha.
Obviamente tendría que tener en cuenta los días que tiene el mes y esas cosas.
¿Alguna idea?

ts

```
public fecha;
 let date: Date = new Date();
let dia=date.getDay();
let mes=getMonth();
let anio=date.getFullYear();

console.log(dia+'/'+mes+'/'anio);


agregar_dias=90;
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes agregar dias así :

```
date.setDate(date.getDate() + agregar_dias);
```

Tu código quedaría así:

```
let date:Date;
let date2:Date;

date = new Date();
let dia = date.getDay();
let mes = date.getMonth();
let anio = date.getFullYear();

console.log(dia+'/'+ mes+'/'+ anio);

date2 = new Date();
var agregar_dias = 90;

date2.setDate(date.getDate() + agregar_dias);
let dia1 = date2.getDay();
let mes1 = date2.getMonth();
let anio1 = date2.getFullYear();

console.log(dia1+'/'+ mes1+'/'+anio1);
```

Comment: me salen muchos números, no sé si tenga que poner algo más